# pantheon-files depends on libhandy-1-0 but it is not installable on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, pantheon

I am getting dependency error while installing pantheon-files

```
$ sudo apt install pantheon-files
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pantheon-files : Depends: libhandy-1-0 (>= 0.82.0) but it is not installable
                  Recommends: exfat-fuse but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: tumbler-plugins-extra but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy pantheon-files
pantheon-files:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.5.0+r4099+pkg96~daily~ubuntu6.0.1
  Version table:
     4.5.0+r4099+pkg96~daily~ubuntu6.0.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/daily/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: @Kulfy: thanks for quick reply. I am getting following output 

`apt-cache policy pantheon-file
N: Unable to locate package pantheon-file
`

Yes, i am following this page 
***https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/install-pantheon-file-manager-ubuntu.html***

Comment: @Kulfy
I am getting following output 

`
sudo apt-cache policy pantheon-files
pantheon-files:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.5.0+r4099+pkg96~daily~ubuntu6.0.1
  Version table:
     4.5.0+r4099+pkg96~daily~ubuntu6.0.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/daily/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focal Fossa (20.04) has libhandy-0.0-0 instead and libhandy-1-0 is in Groovy Gorilla (20.10) which is still in development stage. However, you can download and install the deb file for libhandy-1-0 on 20.04 using

```
wget http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libh/libhandy-1/libhandy-1-0_0.90.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libhandy-1-0_0.90.0-1_amd64.deb
```

Once done retry installation of Pantheon Files.

Comment: Thanks @kulfy
it got install with out any error 


But :( unfortunately. When i am trying to open it. it did not open. Once i click icon. 

I new loading symbol comes in top left title bar of ubuntu(20.04), After few second. it get close automatically.

any suggestion please

Comment: @user2473497 I can't reproduce your issue on my machine. Open a terminal and run `io.elementary.files`. Check if there are any logs for the application.

Comment: It is working now thanks Kulfy


but i am not getting any option to change color after doing right-clicking to any folder and file.

Please help me int this as well.

Comment: @user2473497 Do you see boxes at the bottom in right click prompt?

Comment: thanks for your reply. 
No, actually, there is no circle box on the bottom of right-click menu

Comment: @kuify Hey sorry man. I am new to the platform. I did it now. Can you help to get the color menu after right click on the folder/file ?.

Comment: @user2473497 I don't use Pantheon as my primary file manager so, I'm not sure about the issue. However, as I said earlier, you can ask a new question.

Answer (score 4):

I copied the source package from Ubuntu 20.10, and rebuilt it for Ubuntu 20.04 in [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eapandada1/+archive/ubuntu/libhandy-1/). I have also enabled builds for `armhf`, `arm64` and `ppc64el`

To use it, enter the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/libhandy-1
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you can install `libhandy-1-0` with the command

```
sudo apt install libhandy-1-0
```

I have checked that the build works, by using it as a dependency for [Blanket](https://github.com/rafaelmardojai/blanket) [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eapandada1/+archive/ubuntu/blanket).

**Update**: I have backported the recently released version `1.0.0` to the PPA.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that works very well for me is to install the one that was last built by Ubuntu for Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy), as found in their official PPA in here:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/groovy/amd64/libhandy-1-0
The last build was:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/groovy/amd64/libhandy-1-0/1.0.0-2
Which is actually downloadable by doing shift+click on the "downloadable files" for the .deb file.

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution,
Actually, the Last answer is also working. But I got a new solution as well.

we are missing some dependency. We need to install those first and restart pc
Again try to install this file package. Now, you can see the color change on right-click

I am sharing commands bellow. But make sure, you check for the latest file first.

At first, you need to enable universe repository with

`sudo add-apt-repository universe`

and then you can manually download and install a newer version of the library with

`cd ~/Downloads wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/libc/libcloudproviders/libcloudproviders0_0.3.0-1_amd64.deb`

`sudo apt install ./libcloudproviders0_0.3.0-1_amd64.deb`

and then install pantheon-files with

`Sudo apt-get install pantheon-files`

Comment: This answers a completely different issue regarding "color change on right click"

Comment: This does not answer the original question (how to install libhandy-1 in 20.04 to install pantheon-files in Ubuntu 20.04?). You should rather ask a separate question on "How to enable color change on right click in pantheon-files in Ubuntu 20.04?", and write this as an answer to that.