# How can I install libhandy 1.0.0 (or greater) on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, dependencies, compiling, libraries

I'm trying to build a codebase (with Meson), and it's yelling at me that I don't have libhandy. I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270028/pantheon-files-depends-on-libhandy-1-0-but-it-is-not-installable-on-ubuntu-20-04) question, but all links and PPAs mentioned there seem to be dead.

I need libhandy 1.0.0 or greater, and I'm on Ubuntu 20.04. How can I install it (in such a way that it will get picked up by a build system like pkgconfig)?

Comment: Which codebase are you trying to compile? I am interested in trying the new apps with libhandy.

Comment: I did a quick dependency check... You should be able to download it from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/amd64/libhandy-1-0/download) and install it with APT locally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course [the PPA is there](https://launchpad.net/%7Eapandada1/+archive/ubuntu/libhandy-1). I maintain it. I had initially copied the source package from Groovy, and built it in Launchpad (right now, it uses libhandy 1.4 packaged by Panda Jim). I have verified that it works (I used this package in [Blanket](http://github.com/rafaelmardojai/blanket)'s PPA, as a dependency of Blanket). The PPA also hosts packages for `armhf`, `arm64` and `ppc64el`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/libhandy-1
sudo apt update
```

Then install the package (e.g. `libhandy-1-0`, `libhandy-1-dev`) you need.

The PPA has been updated to version 1.4 of libhandy (thanks to the efforts of [Panda Jim](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntuhandbook1)).

Comment: You're correct - I misread the output. The actual error I'm getting when I add the PPA is `Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dolphin-emu/ppa/ubuntu focal Release 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]`. I didn't expect `add-apt-repository` to be giving me error messages about *completely unrelated PPAs* when trying to add a PPA, so I just kind of saw "404" and interpreted that in what I thought was the only reasonable way...

Comment: @JackM please edit the question :)

Comment: @JackM Or ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that works very well for me is to install the one that was last built by Ubuntu for Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy), as found in the Ubuntu's official PPA in here:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/groovy/amd64/libhandy-1-0

The last build was:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/groovy/amd64/libhandy-1-0/1.0.0-2
Which is actually downloadable by doing shift+click on the "downloadable files" for the .deb file.